# Pull Memo data off LG L33L

Tags: internal-storage, lg

I have an old Tracfone LG L33L and have discontinued service on it.  I can access it with USB or wifi.  And there are memo files on it that I was planning on pulling off via USB.  I can't find them.

How to I find and then transfer those files to my laptop?  Or will they even be readable, if I can find them?

I added a memo file and then searched for files created today, and nothing was found.  I searched by file name, and found nothing.  I'm looking in Internal Storage, which is all I see when connected via USB.

Comment: memos are most likely not files (depending on kind) apps usually save data in [databases](https://sqliteforensictoolkit.com/how-not-to-examine-sqlite-wal-files) besides app data isn't saved internal storage, you must examine adb backup files